# Interaction of Master of Intrigue and Tongue of Sun and Moon re: NPC perceptions

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, rogue, languages

First of all, our group assumes that Tongue of the Sun and Moon is similar to Tongues, and that both abilities produce an audible effect that mimics the function of language but does not replicate it. The rules are somewhat vague on what reaching out and touching another creature's ki entails, but this is the stated mechanism by which the monk can understand other languages and allow others to understand what the monk says.

Master of Intrigue states:

> Additionally, you can unerringly mimic the speech patterns and accent of a creature that you hear speak for at least 1 minute, allowing you to pass yourself off as a native speaker of a particular land, provided that you know the language.

Could Tongue of the Sun and Moon fulfill the requirement that a mastermind know the language of the person whom they are listening to, given that the monk can "understand all spoken languages"? **Could a Mastermind Monk pass themselves off as a native speaker of a tongue they don't actually know?**

For context, our party faces regular language barrier challenges within an intrigue-heavy campaign. We have assumed that while understandable, the language produced by the Tongue of the Sun and Moon sounds noticeably distinct from common, or whatever other language a creature would expect to hear. As a consequence, a monk could not effectively impersonate someone who speaks a language they cannot speak, without their obviously garbled ki-enhanced gibberish blowing their cover.

Answer (score 9):

## You're understood, but not as a native speaker

[Tongue of the Sun and Moon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/classes#TongueoftheSunandMoon) states (emphasis mine):

> ...you learn to touch the ki of other minds so that you understand all spoken languages. Moreover, any creature that can understand a language **can understand** what you say.

Note here that while they can understand you, it does not say that you are actually speaking their language. Your quote for Master of Intrigue also does not state that you speak a new language, but only that mimic speech patterns and accent and specifically requires that this only works **if you know the language.**

### No foreign language, no fooling

Unfortunately, because you aren't actually speaking their language an NPC would know what you say, but would also know that you aren't speaking to them in their native language. Close, but no cigar.

Comment: technically, I think you could both mimic them (without understanding) and use Tongue of the Sun and Moon... which might allow you to be understood in what you actually meant while speaking random strung-together phrases of their language as if you were a native speaker.  It would probably come across pretty creepy, actually.

Comment: Thanks NautArch; Ben, that is a horrifying mental picture.

Comment: @BenBarden I'm not sure. The requirement for Mastermind is that you know the language. Tongue doesn 't give you that knowledge, it only makes you understood. But if that was the case...it is horrifying.

Comment: Well, the actual effect is "can unerringly mimic the speech patterns and accent".  The "pass yourself off as a native speaker if you know the language" is a particular trick that that allows you to do.  It's fuzzy enough that it would be DM's call, but I think there's support for it, and I'd personally allow it.